# Insert date only into database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am trying to save only date (ex: `2011/09/26 00:00:00`) from `getdate()`. I am using sql server 2005.

My sql query is going to be like this:

```
Insert into Merchant(startdate) 
values **today's date only**
```

How is it possible?

Comment: So you want to always use 2011/09/26 00:00:00 as your date, right? Keep 2011/09/26 00:00:00 for next week and next month etc?

Comment: It should be depending on date. Martin helped me. Thanks for checking Adel :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO Merchant
(startdate) 
VALUES (DATEADD(DAY,0,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETDATE())))
```

Comment: My only recommendation would be to load 'GetDate()' into a variable prior to your insert.  In this case, it is only called once, but in other select or update operations you will not want your GetDate() math called for each row in the query.

Comment: @Jeff - [This isn't necessary](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/conor_cunningham_msft/archive/2010/04/23/conor-vs-runtime-constant-functions.aspx). If you do `SELECT GETDATE() FROM HugeTable` all rows will have the same value regardless of how long the `SELECT` takes.

Comment: Ah actually I think I may have missed your point. You were talking about the calculation not the `getdate()` evaluation.

Comment: @ MartinSmith how to use your code to get just the date part as "25/04/2018" from getdate() in sqlserver.

Comment: @AnitaMathew - I'd use `SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'dd/MM/yyyy')` for that as long as you are on a version with `FORMAT`

Comment: @MartinSmith it says :FORMAT is not recognized  built-in func in SQL server 2008R2

Answer (score 0):

```
select dateadd(dd,0, datediff(dd,0, GETDATE()))
```

However, if you move to SQL2008, I recommend changing your column to DATE instead of DATETIME.

Comment: I suggest staying away from the shorthand methods - spell out `DAY` for example. Others reading your code will thank you. Background: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

**EDIT** - Revised to account for rounding after midday.

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT, GETDATE())))
```

Here's another apporoach you can try:

```
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 101) AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: `SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(INT, GETDATE()))` rounds up for times after midday.

Comment: Thanks. I've added an alternative method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to the party, but here are my 2 cents:

```
INSERT INTO Merchant
(startdate) 
VALUES (cast(GETDATE() as Date))
```

That, of course, will only work from SQL Server 2008. I'll leave this answer, however, for learning purposes and future references.

Comment: Not available in SQL Server 2005

Comment: @MartinSmith hmm, good point. But I think I'll edit and leave it here for future references. For the sake of learning :)